# Filter entities in index selecting user

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have a problem using AJAX and Rails.
I'm quite new to these two languages, so sorry for any mistake!
I need to filter *Sample* entity selecting in index from a dropdown menù.
I can save the value in a js variable and I can show the value in a html tag, but if I want to pass the value from js file, through ajax, to rails controller, I can't filter the samples, but my terminal says otherwise.
In this picture I show you my js code to take the user_id from dropdown menu and to show and hide the index table if you choose or not the user, and tha ajax request to pass the value to rails.

[image]

Here I have the index action in the rails controller, where I save the parameter passed by ajax in a ruby variable.
Then I filter samples using the parameter (in this way I would expect to see the sample with id equal to the parameter).

[image]

And here there is the terminal response when I choose the user with id = 1.

[image]

I don't know if this is the right way to do the job, and for this reason I need your help, please.
Thank you in advance for any advice.

Comment: seems like you got what you expect, didn't you?

Comment: I think problem is in `@samples = Sample.where(id: user_sample)`, if you want all the samples with `user_id`, then use something like `@samples = Sample.where(user_id: user_sample)` Is this you're looking for?

Comment: Thank you for answer, but it doesn't do what I want, because it returns ever a blank index whit no one sample. But this seems strange because my terminal seems to say the otherwise.

Comment: @Gigi Can you share what your view looks like?